# Not able to see logcat when error comes suddenly start the last activity

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am not able to see the logcat app crash and start the last activity so how can i see the logcat where the error came. please help me.

Comment: change filter to "no filter". It wont clear the logcat no matter what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries i got the answer. Only exception handling can hold the logcat screen or won't let the start new activity.  So you can trace the errors

Answer (score 0):

You should see buttons called 'TODO', 'LOGCAT', 'BUILD' and 'TERMINAL' at the bottom of your Android Studio Window. Click Logcat, run your app and you'll see the error whenever your app crashes.

[image]

Comment: i know this is how i can see logcat but my activity restart so new logcat runs , i m not able to

Comment: are you trying to get a logcat on a specific activity?

Answer (score 0):

Click `logcat` on the down layer of the screen

Or press `Alt+6.`

Then:

1. select the correct emulator name from the first dropdown menu.
2. select correct package name from the second dropdown menu.
3. select  "error"  from the third drop down menu.
4. select "show only selected application" from the last drop down menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try it :

got to logcat  the down layer of the screen

check all of things on below :

1-check ur emuleter name equal ur device if running

for exmaple i have device Nexus_5x_API_25
when i run this device show to me this name in field

2-beside this menu check ur package correct with this project package

for exmaple in my have elhaji.contact  its my packagename

3-set tic on Regex

4- set verbose in menu

5 check u dont write on fieldtext its must be empty

6- set no filter in menu

u can also this picture[image]

sry i cant bad speak english im learning :))